# Apache2 wildcard cert www and non-www domain trouble

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

I've run into a bit of an issue with my SSL. I have a CA-signed wildcard cert by Digicert. I have installed it properly and am attempting to use it to access my sites, comp.org and www.comp.org via https. https://www.comp.org works just fine. However, when I attempt to access https://comp.org directly, I get a connection_timed_out error on google chrome. To validate that my cert is indeed a wildcard, I ran the command:

`openssl x509 -in /root/comp.crt -noout -text | grep Subject:`

My result was as follows:

`Subject: C=US, L=Town, ST=State, O=Comp, Inc., CN=*.comp.org`

To my understanding, I should be able to access both comp.org and www.comp.org with this, right? However, only www.comp.org is working for me. My best guess is that this has something to do with the way that I am setting up my virtualhost? Currently, my setup in default-ssl is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName *.comp.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    #All the rest of that SSLEngine jazz
```

To be clear, I do NOT want to do the non-www to www redirect. I know of this method as a feasible workaround, but I want to use this as a learning experience to better understand how virtualhosts and SSL certs work, as I am fairly new to all of this.

Hence, I would like my customers to be able to access both comp.org and www.comp.org. Incidentally, both sites display the same content, so I don't need to dictate different paths or anything like that in the virtualhosts. Just trying to learn here.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate, as far as I can see, is correct.

You should add a ServerAlias line, and change the ServerName in order to explicity use www.comp.org:

```
ServerName www.comp.org
ServerAlias comp.org
```

Or viceversa.

```
ServerName comp.org
ServerAlias www.comp.org
```

The only thing that will differ is the hostname used in the logfiles, that will be the one specified in the ServerName clause.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that already, and it didn't seem to help. Something to note: My web server is running on our local system, which is where I'm running the tests. However, due to circumstances outside of my control, comp.org resolves to a different local IP than www.comp.org does. Could this be the cause of the problem? www.comp.org is on 192.168.0.206 but due to some server issues we've had in the past comp.org resolves to 192.168.0.5.

Comment: Are that IP on different machines or on the same host? And if both belongs to the same host, is apache configured to listen to both?

Comment: Well, 206 is our virtualized webserver. 5 is our domain controller. However, apache is configured to listen to all requests. http://comp.org works just fine. All the webserver stuff is only running on a single machine.

Comment: EDIT: It looks like http://comp.org does not work either. This is odd, as I've seen it functioning in the past, and nothing that I have done has changed any of the non-ssl stuff. I'll have to look into this more closely.